# get height of dom element after using get(index)

Tags: jquery, height

I use the following (not working code):

```
var height = $("#rows").children().get(index).height();
```

The thing is that `.get(index)` returns the DOM element.
So after that the height() method does not exist.

How can I work around this problem?

Comment: Please add `HTML` also. Will help to solve the problem

Comment: var height = $("#rows").children().eq(index).height();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **[eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)**

```
var height = $("#rows").children().eq(index).height();
```

or

```
var height = $("#rows").children().get(index).clientHeight;
```

NOTE: `get()` will be converted to javascript object so there is no height() method in javascript